# Power BI | Query execution failed: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found

Tags: oauth, powerbi, gcloud

I have this error when i connect from Power BI to  BigQuery.

- The query work fine from WebUI Google Big Query
- I import data from Google Drive

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Did you grant permissions to the user to access the table?

Comment: Yep, but i have same problem...